# Eclipse antlr4 NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I was making basic antlr project that read parse tree and print it.However, when I tried to run this, they can't initiallize my main class.
Error massage was: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/ParseTree
I'm using antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar
I set class path using Build path to use jar file, and I tried project clean, refresh my project as I found in internet that they told me to do so at noclassfounderror. What is wrong with my project?

Comment: Did you put the Antlt JAR on the **runtime** classpath too?

Comment: I put jar in modulepath at build path

Comment: That is not what I asked ...........

Comment: I changed path from modulepath to classpath and it works. I think. At least the program runs. I think I might have solved it. Thank you

Comment: Sorry... I'm not good at using eclipse so I needed to find out what is runtime classpath

Comment: OK so you are trying to run it from within Eclipse, and that is when it is failing?

Comment: No I fixed it. That was just saying. Thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.